# Setting variable price for in-app-purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a ride-sharing app, where passengers pay for the distance they traveled. From what I read, this should be accomplished by a `consumable manageable products`, but they do not offer the possibility to set the variable price.

As a work-around I can imagine myself defining a list of products like:

- 10 $
- 1 $
- .5 $
- .2 $
- .01 $

so that I can represent any price by combining the products:

```
14.65 $  ->  10 $ + 4 x 1 $ + .5 $ + 15 x .01 $
```

but this seems to be... you know...

Am I missing something here? are there any possibility to make it straight-forward?

TIA

Comment: To make it straight-forward, integrate your app with a payment gateway instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question at google support, and they said, that no, currently no variable price is supported.